# FFMPEG Loudnorm reading JSON data

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I tried to normalize some audio files using FFMPEG Loudnorm as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1312885/476565).

However, in Python, I don't understand how to read data info from 1st pass.

My code:

```
getLoud =  subprocess.Popen(f"ffmpeg -i {file_path} -filter:a loudnorm=print_format=json -f null NULL", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
getLoud =  getLoud.read().decode()
# parse json_str:
jsonstr_loud = json.loads(getLoud)
```

This gives me `"errorMessage": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"`

I tried also this:

```
os.system(f"ffmpeg -i {file_path} -filter:a loudnorm=print_format=json -f null NULL")
```

and it outputs:

```
ffmpeg version N-60236-gffb000fff8-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers...
...
[Parsed_loudnorm_0 @ 0x5921940] 
{
    "input_i" : "-9.33",
    "input_tp" : "-0.63",
    "input_lra" : "0.60",
    "input_thresh" : "-19.33",
    "output_i" : "-24.08",
    "output_tp" : "-15.40",
    "output_lra" : "0.60",
    "output_thresh" : "-34.08",
    "normalization_type" : "dynamic",
    "target_offset" : "0.08"
}
```

In Python, how can I use those parameters, such as `input_i`, `input_tp` etc. that I need for the 2nd pass?

I can't use `ffmpeg-normalize` because I'm using FFMPEG as a Layer in Lambda.

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here and should be asked on [SO]. I voted to migrate the question. You can simply use the function I have in ffmpeg-normalize: https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize/blob/db624b329a325d938053d4ec7e9596e5a3e83843/ffmpeg_normalize/_streams.py#L235-L282

Answer (score 2):

Kind of hacky, possibly flaky, but I did this and it has been plugging away at about 1GB an hour without a problem for at least 24 hours.

```
first_step_output = subprocess.run(
    "ffmpeg "
    f"-i \"{full_path}\" "
    "-af loudnorm=print_format=json "
    "-f null "
    "-",
    shell=True,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
if first_step_output.returncode == 0:
    output = json.loads(
        "{" + first_step_output.stderr.decode().split("{")[1]
    )
```